# Creating a new method 'predict_proba' in keras.models.Model class that returns the output of existing method 'predict'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a Functional API to create a model which I then use for calibration using CalibratedClassifierCV. Unfortunately it throws an error saying that predict_proba cannot be used with a Functional model. In my case, I have only one output so `model.predict()` would work just as well as `model.predict_proba()`. I was wondering if it is possible to create a new method in the keras.models.Model class called `predict_proba` that just returns the output of predict.

So far I have tried this:

```
def predict_proba(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10, 
                  workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False):
    
    return keras.models.Model.predict( x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, 
                          max_queue_size=max_queue_size, 
                          workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
```

But it throws me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-6bb11e61a234> in <module>
     81 calibrator_0 = CalibratedClassifierCV(model_0, cv='prefit')
     82 
---> 83 calibrator_0.fit(X_test_0, y_test_0, sample_weight = w_test_0)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    153             calibrated_classifier = _CalibratedClassifier(
    154                 base_estimator, method=self.method)
--> 155             calibrated_classifier.fit(X, y, sample_weight)
    156             self.calibrated_classifiers_.append(calibrated_classifier)
    157         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    332         Y = label_binarize(y, classes=self.classes_)
    333 
--> 334         df, idx_pos_class = self._preproc(X)
    335         self.calibrators_ = []
    336 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\calibration.py in _preproc(self, X)
    291                 df = df[:, np.newaxis]
    292         elif hasattr(self.base_estimator, "predict_proba"):
--> 293             df = self.base_estimator.predict_proba(X)
    294             if n_classes == 2:
    295                 df = df[:, 1:]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\wrappers\scikit_learn.py in predict_proba(self, x, **kwargs)
    262     """
    263     kwargs = self.filter_sk_params(Sequential.predict_proba, kwargs)
--> 264     probs = self.model.predict_proba(x, **kwargs)
    265 
    266     # check if binary classification

<ipython-input-37-6bb11e61a234> in predict_proba(x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
      5                   workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False):
      6 
----> 7     return keras.models.Model.predict( x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose, steps=steps, callbacks=callbacks, 
      8                           max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
      9                           workers=workers, use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I want to define this function so that when a keras.models.Model object calls `predict_proba`, say using `model.predict_proba(x,..)`, it returns the output of `model.predict(x,..)`.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this simple fix seems to work:

```
keras.models.Model.predict_proba = keras.models.Model.predict
```

Now I can use a functional model with `CalibratedClassifierCV`.